# Requirejs and Threejs OrbitControls how to get it working?

Tags: javascript, three.js, requirejs

I'm struggling to get OrbitControls to work with requirejs.

My configuration is following:

I tried to get it working with the help of this post
[RequireJS and THREE.js Orbit Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306959/requirejs-and-three-js-orbit-controls), but its not.

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: './js',
    deps: ['main'],
    paths: {
        threejs: 'three/three.min',
        orbitControls: 'three/controls/OrbitControls',
    },
    shim: {
       'threejs': {
            exports: 'THREE'
        },
        'orbitControls': {
            deps: ['threejs']
        }
    }
});
```

Then I'm defining THREE in main.js
Again looked help from github post https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9602

```
define('threejs', function ( THREE ) {
    window.THREE = THREE;
    return THREE;
});
```

Then Im calling the Orbit controls in my scene

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
```

And gettign an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: THREE.OrbitControls is not a constructor
```

I'm not sure if I need to call the orbitControls in the define section of my class

```
define(['orbitControls'], function() {
    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
})
```

But if I do this, I'm getting an error of

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
```

Which I do know that the THREE is defined because the rest of the scene is rendering as it should.

I am hoping there is someone who has already configured this and might give me an helping hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out how to get it working and want to help others.

First I needed to wrap the OrbitControls.js with a basic require define function

```
define(['threejs'], function(THREE) {
    /* OrbitControls.js */
});
```

Then in class what is using the controls must define 'orbitControls'

```
define(['orbitControls'], function() {
    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
});
```

Then the addEventListener needs to be modified like:

```
controls.addEventListener('change', function() {
                render();
                return false;
            });
```

Comment: What do you mean with "wrap the OrbitControls.js"? Are you inserting the OrbitControls.js code in the define? I have the same problem you had and haven't been able to fix it.